# Running an Ansible playbook via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am using Jenkins to take a number of parameters, generate an ansible-playbook command and run it. My Jenkins server is also my Ansible server.

My shell says ::

```
echo $ESXi_IP
echo $VM_NAME
echo $NIC1_MAC
echo $NIC2_MAC
echo $NIC3_MAC
echo $NIC4_MAC
echo $ESXi_HOSTNAME
echo $PLAYBOOK

ansible-playbook $PLAYBOOK --extra-vars "esxi_ip=$ESXi_IP vm_name=$VM_NAME nic1_mac=$NIC1_MAC nic2_mac=$NIC2_MAC nic3_mac=$NIC3_MAC nic4_mac=$NIC4_MAC esxi_hostname=$ESXi_HOSTNAME"
```

When I run the Job, the output is ::

```
+ ansible-playbook /root/ansible/sc-ece.yaml --extra-vars 'esxi_ip=5.232.66.49 vm_name=JenkinsTest nic1_mac=00:50:C0:A8:01:02 nic2_mac=00:50:0A:A9:37:A5 nic3_mac=00:50:0A:FF:FE:4C nic4_mac=00:50:AC:10:01:65 esxi_hostname=tmolab13-14iamesxi4'
ERROR! the playbook: /root/ansible/sc-ece.yaml could not be found
```

The playbook path is correct. there is no issue in it at all.

What seems to be missing here ?

Comment: add `file $PLAYBOOK` before playbook execution to be 100% sure that file is in place.

Comment: Perhaps file permissions? Is Jenkins running as root?

Comment: Jenkins normally runs as the Jenkins user and the playbook is in `/root` so permissions does seem to be the most likely issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct Matt & Dave. Permissions to the folder was an issue. Thanks !